# Escaping javascript entities in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to escape javascript entities on client side. For example :-

If my input string is `tes"t` result should be `tes\"t`

Is there any inbuilt function provided by jquery for this ?

Comment: Uh... if the stuff's already in JavaScript, how do you want JavaScript to be able to escape it? It's already been parsed!

Comment: Like the way StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript does.

Comment: encodeURIComponent maybe ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Could you show a practical use case for this, or why you want to do it? Smells of an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really crazy, almost stupid shot in the dark on my part, but...

If you're using a server-side language like PHP to output variables' contents into JavaScript, you should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) as this handles ALL escaping for you, regardless of the type of variable.

On the other hand, if you're (I really hope you're not) doing something like this:

```
var input = "test"t";
```

And trying to escape that properly while in JavaScript... that's not going to work. It's a syntax error. You need to escape your literals manually.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin van Zonneveld provide a JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s `addslashes` here :
http://phpjs.org/functions/addslashes/

```
function addslashes(str) {
    //   example 1: addslashes("kevin's birthday");
    //   returns 1: "kevin\\'s birthday"

    return (str + '')
    .replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&')
    .replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}
```

Based on this function, I guess you might want to add this function to `prototype` of the `String` like this.

```
if (!String.prototype.addslashes) {
   String.prototype.addslashes = function () {
       return this.replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
   };
}

var str = 'tes"t';
alert(str.addslashes()); // shows 'tes\"t'
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/6F6aN/6/

Hope this helps.